# AngularJS, how to use JSON from child in parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When an item is selected in the select box, I want to use the other field in the parent div. In this case the country.
My code:
**index.php**

```
<div class="field" id="{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="t in getTimes(fieldSelect) track by $index")>
    <select name="drop_down" class="marketSelect">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
    {{item.country}}
</div>
```

**angular.js**

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
        url: 'assets/json/currency.json'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.items = response.data.currency;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Oh shit, JSON is not working");
});
```

Comment: `{{marketSelect.country}}`

Comment: <select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="countryId as (countryName) for country in countryList"></select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ng-model` directive in combination with the `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" 
        ng-model="selectedItem">
</select>
```

Then in your div:

```
{{ selectedItem.country }}
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2pnea19/)

Comment: would also want to use `ng-options`

Comment: Not working :( Maybe it has to do something with the ngRepeat on the div? I have multiple div's, number given by select box